# How to get smartd to ignore an HDD?

Tags: external-hdd, smartctl, smart

I have an external HDD which does not report SMART information properly (it gives nonsense results).

As such, the `smartd` daemon (part of `smartmontools`) keeps giving false alarms on how the device might be failing.

In `/etc/smartmontools/smartd.conf` (I'm using the default, [here](http://pastebin.com/w2f65waW)) I see a bunch of options but none that relate to my need (ignoring the alarms for a specific hard drive - I would like to be able to refer to it e.g. by USB ID, since the entry in `/dev` will vary if I have more devices connected).

I could edit `/usr/libexec/smartmontools/smartdnotify` (the script that `smartd` calls when an event happens) and manually force it to shut up about that specific device, but I'd like to know if there's a less ugly way to do that.

How to get `smartd` to not report any warnings for a specific HDD? I would **not** like to disable the daemon; I would like it to just not care about this specific HDD.

Comment: What's your config look like? Usually it's the other way around, you have to tell it explicitely which HDDs to monitor, not which ones to ignore...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to comment out the `DEVICESCAN` line, and put in lines for individual devices. Mine, for example, looks like this:

```
/dev/sda -d removable -n standby,8 -S on -o on -a \
         -m root -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner \
         -r 194 -R 5 -R 183 -R 187 -s L/../../6/01
/dev/sdb -d removable -n standby,8 -S on -o on -a \
         -m root -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner \
         -r 194 -R 5 -R 183 -R 187 -s L/../../6/06
/dev/sdc -d removable -n standby,8 -S on -o on -a \
         -m root -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner \
         -r 194 -R 5 -R 183 -R 187 -s L/../../7/01
/dev/sdd -d removable -n standby,8 -S on -o on -a \
         -m root -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner \
         -r 194 -R 5 -R 183 -R 187 -s L/../../7/06
/dev/sde -d removable -n standby,8 -S on -o on -a \
         -m root -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner \
         -r 194 -R 5 -R 183 -R 187 -s L/../../6/01
```

You can refer to individual devices in any convenient way; for example, instead of `/dev/sda` I could use `/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c5001fc90b93`, which will track that same disk no matter how its connected.

Answer (score 12):

`-d ignore` is a new directive which allows ignoring a device from DEVICESCAN.

`~$ cat /etc/smartd.conf`

```
#/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_KingSpec_KDM-44VVS14413121 -d ignore
# frustratingly specifying disk by-id doesn't work so fall-back to ignoring sdb
/dev/sdb -d ignore
DEVICESCAN -a -o on -S on -n standby,q -s (S/../.././02|L/../../6/03) -W 4,40,45 -m root
```

Comment: As of smartmontools 7, disk by-id works if you add `-d by-id` option to DEVICESCAN (more details here: https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/1390#comment:2)